# ubuntu add route to DSL modem

Tags: networking

I have a router with two network interfaces: eth0 serves the local net whereas eth1 is connected to my DSL modem.

I have the following entries in interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.0.0
    broadcast 192.168.0.255
    gateway 192.168.0.1
    dns-nameservers 127.0.0.1
    dns-search lala.home
    dns-domain lala.home

auto dsl-provider
iface dsl-provider inet ppp
pre-up /sbin/ifconfig eth1 up # line maintained by pppoeconf
provider dsl-provider

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
```

The DSL modem has the IP address 192.168.1.1

How do I reach the DSL modems web interface from my local network?